# Why does my macro stop at the end of file

Tags: vim

I write a macro which adds a `;` at the end of line and moves the cursor to next line. And I repeatly run this macro to add `;`s to every line of the buffer.

Here is my input

```
qaA;ESCjq
1000@a
```

And here is my question. My file has only 5 lines, and I repeat the macro 1000 times. It should add a lot of `;`s at the end of the last line, but what vim does is just stopping at the end of file. I want to know which mechanism in vim leads to this.

I believe it's a simple question, but I just cannot find any official doc to prove it. So I hope there are some doc that describe this mechanism formally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short…

- `j` moves the cursor down one line.
- This is impossible to do when the cursor is on the last line so Vim throws an error.
- Your macro stops being executed because of that error.

AFAIK, this is not documented in a very straightforward way. `:help 10.1` is completely silent about error handling and `:help @` is not really helpful either:

```
[…]
The register is executed like a mapping, that means
that the difference between 'wildchar' and 'wildcharm'
applies, and undo might not be synced in the same way.
[…]
```

That passing reference to mappings is the only line we can follow and, without a proper tag, it's a tiny one.

Anyway, only after a tentative `:help mapping` and a lot of scrolling do we get to the bottom of it:

```
                                                        *map-error*
Note that when an error is encountered (that causes an error message or might
cause a beep) the rest of the mapping is not executed.  This is Vi-compatible.
```

---

Now, using a large `[count]` to make sure a macro is executed as many times as necessary without having to count is akin to brute force. Effective, sort of, but not very efficient.

A better way to use macros in this case would be to not include the motion in the recording:

```
qaA;<ESC>q
```

and play it back with `:help :normal` and a proper `:help :range`:

```
:%normal @a
```

But, frankly, why go through all that trouble when you can do:

```
:%s/$/;
```

?

Comment: You're right, `:%s/$/;` is better in this case. And the explanation of the mechanism helps as well. Thanks for your detailed reply.

Answer (score 3):

The best I could find was this part of [`:help @`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#%40):

> The register is executed like a mapping

In combination with [`:help map-error`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#map-error):

> Note that when an error is encountered (that causes an error message or beep)
> the rest of the mapping is not executed.  This is Vi-compatible.

Pressing `j` at the bottom-most line of a buffer causes such an error.

The weak spot of this reasoning is that the count is applied differently in `@` than in a mapping.

Creating a mapping that appends a semi-colon and calling it 1000 times *will* add 1000 semi-colons. Creating a mapping that goes down  and then adds a semi-colon (e.g. `:nnoremap <f2> jA;<Esc>`) will fail on the last line of a buffer. The explanation works if you think of `1000@x` as "create a mapping that contains the commands in `x` 1000 times."

Two more things:

Do you really want to add that many semi-colons? Isn't it nice to have a piece of software that does what you *want*, with or without it being documented?

For the sake of completeness, the way to add semi-colons is with either of the two commands:

```
:%normal A;
:%s/$/;/
```

Technically, the macro applies a semi-colon to the current line and each line below which would be

```
:.,$s/$/;/
```